# Chrome Packaged App passing file from the command line (via launchData)

Tags: file, command-line-arguments, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to write a Chrome packaged app that will eventually accept files as arguments from the command line, but I can't figure out how to make it work.  Here's what I'm doing:

**manifest.json**:

```
...
"file_handlers" : {
    "text" : {
        "types" : [ "*" ],
        "title" : "File Opener"
    }
},
...
```

**my-background-page.js**:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function (launchData) {
    chrome.app.window.create('my-file.html', { ... }, function (win) {
        win.contentWindow.launchData = launchData;
    });
});
```

(I expect `launchData` to have data filled in on what files were passed via the command line.)

**command**:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app-id=my-app-id "C:\path\to\file.txt"
```

When I execute the above command, the packaged app opens up all fine-and-dandy, but `launchData` is undefined.

Am I missing something obvious here?  I'm running Chrome 27 on Windows 7 here, and would really like to get this to work!

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's how this turned out: The file I was passing via the command line had a MIME-type unknown to Chrome (27), and currently when this happens, the file gets omitted from the `launchData`.  Fortunately this is fixed in Chrome 28 (I believe), and I have confirmed that the app works in Chrome Canary (which is up to 29 beta currently).

See [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=219402) issue for further reference.